# Fastest way to get number of white pixels in a binary image using OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

What is the fastest way to get number of white pixels in a binary picture using OpenCV? Is there something faster than using two for loops and accessing the image pixel by pixel?

Comment: Is the image in true greyscale, or is it a binary image?

Comment: @Aurelius: It's actually binary image, I should have written that in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most succinct way to accomplish this is:

```
cv::Mat image, mask;    //image is CV_8UC1
cv::inRange(image, 255, 255, mask);
int count = cv::countNonZero(mask);
```

If you are operating on a binary image, then the call to `cv::inRange()` is unnecessary, and simply `cv::countNonZero()` will suffice.

Although any method must iterate through all the pixels, this may be able to harness OpenCV's built-in `parallel_for_()`, which allows parallel execution.

If your image is continuous, you can iterate through all the data using a single loop.

Comment: Thanks, cv::inRange is what I wanted! I'm actually using OpenCV through EmguCV wrapper (in C#), and this one line speeded my program for about 40%. Do you have any idea why looping in two for loops is so much slower?

Comment: I am not very familiar with C#, but I believe it does bounds checking when you iterate in a loop, which could explain some of the performance difference.

Comment: Thanks, bounds checking is really slowing down things. But event after I've disabled bounds checking, for a very large picture (10240x7680) CV function takes about 70ms, and two for loops take about 350ms. After using Parallel.For, the two loops approach took about 200ms, but that's still much longer that OpenCV implementation.

Comment: Many OpenCV functions also employ hardware optimizations. cv::countNonZero()` in particular is vectorized using SSE, which accounts for the remainder of the performance difference.