# how much white is in a frame using OpenCV ?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a GRAY image and I want to know the percentage of the white color on it. I know that I can do these with two for-loop that check the color of  each pixel, but I was wondring if there any better method to do this ? 
here is an example the image that I want to analyze :
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to get number of white pixels in gray image using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929190/fastest-way-to-get-number-of-white-pixels-in-gray-image-using-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the images are black and white (no other grey levels) you could use `cvCountNonZero`.

Comment: Note you won't get any performance benefit out of and the code needed to make it yourself is minimal

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov That's not necessarily true. `cv::CountNonZero()` contains some SSE optimizations, so there *will* be a performance benefit in some cases. I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16929350/1601291) a question which might be relevant.